# tmux garbage character when execute tail -f command

Tags: tmux

I use tmux as a beginner.
I use gnome terminal in Ubunutu 16.04.I split the window into 4 panes.When I execute `tail -f FILE` command in the top-right pane,so much content is emerging.At the same time,I find that some garbage characters come out in the left margin on the top-left pane?
How could I do to solve the problem?
thanks very much.

I use tmux 2.1.My tmux conf content is as follows:

```
# change prefix-key
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-f

# solve gibberish problem in copy-paste mode
set -g set-clipboard off

# up
bind-key k select-pane -U
# down
bind-key j select-pane -D
# left
bind-key h select-pane -L
# right
bind-key l select-pane -R
```

I just test it in Tmux 2.5,the same problem exists.

Comment: how does your tmux.conf look like , which version of tmux do you use? You could try to use the last version of tmux (2.5 or 2.6-rc1).

Comment: I have updated my problem description.I perfer to find a solution by not updating my tmux.
thanks.